# getApproximateCreationDateTime() API not available with DynamoDB StreamRecord object

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm working on a POC around *DynamoDB Streams* and was following this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.LowLevel.Walkthrough.CompleteProgram.html).

The `StreamRecord` object I get from calling `Record.getDynamodb()` method, doesn't seem to have the `ApproximateCreationDateTime` attribute, as mentioned in the [javadocs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/StreamRecord.html#getApproximateCreationDateTime--) here.

I was wondering if this field has been deprecated and the docs have not been updated or if I'm going wrong else where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your SDK version. SDK version [1.10.5 introduced Streams](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/ebdfabf87208d5cbc733b7b020b82dedbf0b8c7a/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/StreamRecord.java) to the API, and SDK version [1.11.7 added approximateCreationDateTime](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/StreamRecord.java#L33) to the StreamRecord class.